# How to convert between F# and C# tuples?

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I am writing an F# interop class to be used from C#. I thought that F# had an implicit conversion from .NET Tuple<> type (similar to IEnumerable treated as seq), so I wrote the following code:

```
type MyClass() = 
    member this.MyMethod (t: Tuple<int, int>) =
        let meaningOfLife (t : int * int) = 42
        meaningOfLife t
```

This code fails to compile with the following error:
**error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type int * int but here has type Tuple**

Then how to convert tuples between C# and F# (and back)?

Comment: Both types are different. You could write `meaningOfLife (t.item1, t.item2)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're targeting .NET 4.0 and above, you don't need to specify the object Tuple. F# tuples get automatically compiled to Tuple. You can use:

```
type MyClass() = 
  member this.MyMethod (t: int * int) =
    let meaningOfLife (t : int * int) = 42
    meaningOfLife t
```

And it should work fine from C#.

Comment: Still, I don't really get why type inference treats .NET tuple and F# tuple to be different.